# Фильтрация пользователей по нескольким параметрам. Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

пытаюсь сделать фильтровать пользователей по нескольким параметрам:

Есть три свойства типа чекбокс, которые проставлены у каждого пользователя. Фильтр битрикс работает так: ГРУППА1 И ГРУППА2 стоят галочки то показывает пользователей, у которых стоят галочки одновременно и та и эта группа. Если мне надо вывести Пользователей ГРУППА1 ИЛИ ГРУППА2 то перестает показывать.

```
$test_value = Array(
array(
    "LOGIC" => "OR",
    "UF_TMC1" => $filter1["UF_TMC1"],
    "UF_TMC2" => $filter2["UF_TMC2"],
    "UF_TMC3" => $filter3["UF_TMC3"],
),
 "GROUPS_ID" => "7",
);
$arSelect = array('SELECT' => array('UF_SURNAME', 'UF_NAME', 'UF_MIDNAME', 
 'GROUP_ID', 'UF_TMC1', 'UF_TMC2', 'UF_TMC3'));
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="ID"), ($order = "asc"), $test_value, 
$arSelect);
while($reg = $rsUsers->Fetch()){
$arUses = $reg;
$mailUser11[] = $arUses["EMAIL"];
}
```

Comment: Ну а вы читали мануал - возможность искать через `LOGIC => OR` существует для `CUser::GetList`?

Comment: @u_mulder в мануалах вообще мало что написано, по этому приходиться делать всякое. Подскажите как поступить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй D7 API:

```php
$rsUsers = \Bitrix\Main\UserTable::getList([
    'select' => [
        'UF_NAME',
        'UF_MIDNAME',
        'UF_SURNAME',
    ],
    'filter' => [
        [
            'LOGIC' => 'OR',
            'UF_TMC1' => $filter1['UF_TMC1'],
            'UF_TMC2' => $filter1['UF_TMC2'],
            'UF_TMC3' => $filter1['UF_TMC3'],
        ],
        'GROUPS_ID' => 7,
    ],
    'order' => ['ID' => 'asc'],
]);

while ($reg = $rsUsers->fetch())
{
    // ..
}
```

Comment: почему оригинального стиля битрикса не придерживаться array()?

Comment: Может еще на php5.3 программировать? Кстати, а условия для `OR` разве не должны быть отдельными массивами?

Comment: Потому что начиная с php 4 это стало ненужным, к тому же здорово экономит время при написании кода большого объема и повышает читаемость кода

Comment: Условия для `OR` могут быть массивами, а могут и не быть, зависит от конкретной задачи. В большинстве случаев объявление отдельных массивов не является необходимым